# How can I show a maintenance page?

Tags: sails.js

I'd like to show a maintenance page on my site. I plan on saving a Boolean value to the db in order to control when to show the page or not. How can I have the maintenance page show for just my controller routes? I'd like to continue to have sails serve scripts, stylesheets, and images normally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a policy to achieve this.

```
// api/policies/inMaintenance.js

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    var maintenanceMode = ... // get the value
    if (maintenanceMode) return res.view('maintenance');
    next();
}


// config/policies.js

module.exports.policies = {
    '*': 'inMaintenance',
    ...
}
```

In your `views` folder add `maintenance.ejs`.
All the assets will still be available.

There is one drawback to this approach though, if in `config/routes.js` you have a route pointing directly to a view it will not go through the policy. Thus, you need all routes to be handled by controllers.

You can check the [Sails documentation on policies](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Policies) to better understand how they work.